# how to make predictions using my date time (Random forest model)

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I have made this Random Forest model to predict if a stock market day will have an up day or down day.
and my goal is to get a 1 for up days and 0 for down days by passing in a date-time like this

2020-05-12 00:00:00-04:00
I was thinking that it would work with this line of code but obviously I'm not understanding something since it does not work 
rf_random.predict(2020-05-12 00:00:00-04:00)

---

Here is my dataframe

---

```
time                         close  high   low    open   volume    c_in_p   down_days up_days RSI

2016-06-27 00:00:00-04:00    57.61  58.76  57.05  58.76  31954614  -1.97    1.97      0.00    19.832891
2016-06-28 00:00:00-04:00    59.50  59.55  58.26  59.19  24884353   1.89    0.00      1.89    35.990316
2016-06-29 00:00:00-04:00    61.20  61.21  60.00  60.33  18107419   1.70    0.00      1.70    47.063366
```

---

here is the code for my model

---

```
# New Random Forest Classifier to house optimal parameters
rf = RandomForestClassifier()

# Specfiy the details of our Randomized Search
rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = random_grid, n_iter = 100, cv = 5, verbose=5, random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)

# Fit the random search model
rf_random.fit(X_train, y_train)


Fitting 5 folds for each of 100 candidates, totalling 500 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 2 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  14 tasks      | elapsed:   25.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  68 tasks      | elapsed:  1.5min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 158 tasks      | elapsed:  3.7min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 284 tasks      | elapsed:  8.2min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 446 tasks      | elapsed: 12.6min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 500 out of 500 | elapsed: 14.3min finished
RandomizedSearchCV(cv=5, error_score=nan,
                   estimator=RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True,
                                                    ccp_alpha=0.0,
                                                    class_weight=None,
                                                    criterion='gini',
                                                    max_depth=None,
                                                    max_features='auto',
                                                    max_leaf_nodes=None,
                                                    max_samples=None,
                                                    min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
                                                    min_impurity_split=None,
                                                    min_samples_leaf=1,
                                                    min_samples_split=2,
                                                    min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                                                    n_estimators=100,
                                                    n_jobs...
                   param_distributions={'bootstrap': [True, False],
                                        'max_depth': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60,
                                                      70, 80, 90, 100, None],
                                        'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', None,
                                                         'log2'],
                                        'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 7, 12, 14,
                                                             16, 20],
                                        'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10, 20, 30,
                                                              40],
                                        'n_estimators': [200, 400, 600, 800,
                                                         1000, 1200, 1400, 1600,
                                                         1800]},
                   pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', random_state=42, refit=True,
                   return_train_score=False, scoring=None, verbose=5)
```

---

```
'''
    ACCURACY
'''
# Once the predictions have been made, then grab the accuracy score.
print('Correct Prediction (%): ', accuracy_score(y_test, rf_random.predict(X_test), normalize = True) * 100.0)


'''
    CLASSIFICATION REPORT
'''
# Define the traget names
target_names = ['Down Day', 'Up Day']

# Build a classifcation report
report = classification_report(y_true = y_test, y_pred = y_pred, target_names = target_names, output_dict = True)

# Add it to a data frame, transpose it for readability.
report_df = pd.DataFrame(report).transpose()
display(report_df)
print('\n')

'''
    FEATURE IMPORTANCE
'''
# Calculate feature importance and store in pandas series
feature_imp = pd.Series(rand_frst_clf.feature_importances_, index=X_Cols.columns).sort_values(ascending=False)
display(feature_imp)


Correct Prediction (%):  66.80327868852459
               precision    recall      f1-score    support

Down Day       0.623932     0.629310    0.626609    116.000000
Up Day         0.661417     0.656250    0.658824    128.000000
accuracy       0.643443     0.643443    0.643443    0.643443
macro avg      0.642674     0.642780    0.642716    244.000000
weighted avg    0.643596    0.643443    0.643509    244.000000


MACD                    0.213449
k_percent               0.183975
r_percent               0.181395
Price_Rate_Of_Change    0.156800
RSI                     0.150577
On Balance Volume       0.113804
dtype: float64
```

---

```
rf_random.best_estimator_

RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None,
                       criterion='gini', max_depth=20, max_features=None,
                       max_leaf_nodes=None, max_samples=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=12, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=800,
                       n_jobs=None, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
                       verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

---

### Here I would of ask for my prediction but it doesn't work

```
rf_random.predict(2020-05-12 00:00:00-04:00)

  File "<ipython-input-51-788cba99b288>", line 1
    rf_random.predict(2020-05-12 00:00:00-04:00)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: you need to put the date between quotations `rf_random.predict('2020-05-12 00:00:00-04:00')`

Comment: what are your X_train and y_train datasets? the shape and number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

So why wouldn't `rf_random.predict("2020-05-12 00:00:00-04:00")` work? the model doesn't actually learn from the date. Your model needs values for close, high, low, open, volume, c_in_p, down_days, up_days, and RSI to make a prediction. It has to be in the same format as `X_train`.

I know it's always easy to be negative, but just a couple of big picture issues for the record:

1. You're using the future to predict the past with random CV partitioning
2. A useful model must be evaluated on how it performs in the future
3. The dataset is an equally spaced series, so you could use time series approaches to use calendar based events to improve predictions. This solves the issue where you would need to know tomorrow's close/high/low/volume to predict whether tomorrow goes up or down.
4. You're predicting something that has a lot of difficult to explain volatility, therefore it is a poor use case for any machine learning model to learn from. If I made a model that was truly even 60% accurate at predicting whether the market goes up or down tomorrow, I'd be a billionaire!

Comment: than you very much ill be looking into time series to hopefully fix that issue and I know this is a huge mountain of a problem but I'm enjoying the challenge a lot and learning even more from it